# How to use wordpress website for generating passive income?

Tags: wordpress, money

I started a wordpress website a few days ago but now I dont have much time to update it regularly.  My hosting plan is multi-domain plan with unlimited webspace from Hostgator.  I would like to use it for generating passive income without my having to update it.

Please suggest me some good ways to generate decent passive income.

Thank you,

FJ.

Comment: Put it some advertisement on it. But without traffic, it will not generated any money